# Powershell script behaves differently when ran in SQL Server Agent job

Tags: powershell, sql-agent-job

OS: Windows Server 2019 Standard 
SQL: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Standard CU28 
PS version: 5.1.17763.2268

I've made a simple script to check if share is accessible before doing restore of databases. If the share is not accessible, it loops until the share becomes accessible.
Script is the first step in SQL Agent job and is set as PowerShell type.

```
while(!(Test-Path \\192.168.1.92\Share\)) 
    {
        Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "DB_Refresh" -EventID 1001 -EntryType Information -Message "Backup share is not accessible!" -Category 1
        sleep 30
    }
    Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "DB_Refresh" -EventID 1001 -EntryType Information -Message "Backup share is accessible!" -Category 1
```

When I ran the script in PS ISE it works as it should. When I ran it in SQL Agent job step, negation works just the opposite as it should. When share is accessible it will loop and when it is not accessible it will not loop.

Any thoughts why does it behave like that? I have tried with -Not instead exclamation mark, but it behaves same.

Comment: What's your error action preference set to?  Could be `!(Test-Path '\\iDontExist\iDontExist' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)` causing you issues.  The reason you only see it in SQL?  Maybe the SQL service is running under an account that doesn't have network access  access to the share?

Comment: Try setting it to Stop, and adding a try/catch so you can report the issue in the catch block, rather than relying on the while condition alone.

Comment: @JohnLBevan you were right! It returns false, like the account doesn't have an access to the share.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
while(!(Test-Path \\192.168.1.92\Share\))
```

With:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\192.168.1.92\Share"
while(!(Test-Path P:\))
```

I'm not sure if it will work to test if a share is accessible, as you want, but this solution works for accessing files on network shares. For example:

While this doesn't work:

```
$Content = Get-Content -Path "\\192.168.1.92\Share\file.txt"
```

This works fine:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\192.168.1.92\Share"
$Content = Get-Content -Path "P:\file.txt"
```